# Why the need to update MacOS for iOS 14.5

Tags: macos, ios

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 14.5... Then my Mac (an old Mac Pro running MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave) put up a dialog saying I needed an update for the Mac to work with the iPhone.  So I updated.

But what did that update do?

Comment: Probably an iTunes (background/plugin/service) update. I saw similar on earlier iOS 14 updates, also on Mojave, old Mac Pro.

Comment: There was a 'learn more' button...

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, there was a 'learn more' button.  But it links to a generic web page, not revealing the contents of the update.  I think you were right about iTunes update.  I find that 'iTunes.Helper.app' has a modification date of 4am today.

Comment: It used to always require an iTunes update every so often before you could install the latest iOS through it. As there are no more iTunes updates, there needs to be some background tweak. It seems they're not going to tell us in any more detail. Someone would need to filter changed files before & after [which is way beyond my ability, or concern tbh;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, `softwareupdate --history | head ` may help

Comment: @lhf - ah, cool. That might just have found it. Added to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar Mac & OS, just saw the same notification - being prepared for it i followed through the Learn More… link to [Apple KB - If you see "Software update is required to connect to your iOS device" on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/HT208831)

> When you connect your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch to a Mac with macOS 10.11 or later, you might need to update the software on your Mac in order for it to recognise your iOS device. Learn what to do.
>
> If your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch has a newer version of iOS than is supported by your Mac, you may see this alert: "A software update is required to connect to your iOS device. Would you like to download and install this update now?"
>
> [image: Window that shows a software update is required to connect to iPhone]
>
> Click Install to download and install the software so your Mac can update or sync your iOS device. If you continue to see this alert, make sure that your software on your Mac and iTunes are up-to-date.

From comments - `softwareupdate --history | head`  may help figure out what was updated.
I tried it on mine, though I'd also run the new security & Safari updates. There was one other item shown as updated with a timestamp that matches my iOS update, though to version 1.0.0.0 which doesn't seem greatly helpful.

```
macOS Mojave Security Update 2021-003      10.14.6    27/04/2021, 7:53:05 pm
Safari                                     14.1       27/04/2021, 7:53:05 pm
Mobile Device                              1.0.0.0    27/04/2021, 4:46:37 pm
```

Comment: Good.  In my case, "mobile device 1.0.0.0" is the one with time stamp agreeing with this update.