# Stop the message 'A software update is required to connect to your iPad' without doing a software update

Tags: mac, ipad, software-update

I'm not interested in updating any software at this point. I would like this message to stop being displayed. Is there way to stop it from being displayed? I would prefer a System Preferences solution, but I'm also comfortable at the command line.

I'm currently running MacOS 10.15.5 and IPadOS 14.4.

Comment: Why not just run the connection update? It doesn't hurt anything. It doesn't actually update anything except the Mobile Device software. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419560/why-the-need-to-update-macos-for-ios-14-5

Comment: Or don't connect the iPad to the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Usually this is a very small update which allows your more recent iPad running iOS 14, to connect to your Mac running a macOS version pre-Big Sur.

Comment: Sorry - I did not include the OS information. I'm currently running MacOS 10.15.5 and IPadOS 14.4.