# why after updating my iphone and trying to hotspot to my mac air, both updated, a get the message: a software update is required to connect to <MAC>

Tags: iphone, software-update

This message comes up after I have updated, or factory reset my phone and I try to hotspot to my mac air. It has been happening for a few years now, I cannot get rid off the box however I can still hotspot without downloading the unknown software.
It shows a black image of a phone, it reads: "would you like to download and update this software now? Use of this software is subject to the original license software agreement(s) that accompany the software being updated". When I click the info the first time, it took me nowhere, after a few attempts it lead me to an apple support page that lack reasoning behind the proposed update.

Comment: Your computer needs a small update to communicate with your now-updated phone

Comment: Thank you Ezekiel, but the computer is able to communicate with the recently updated phone without having downloaded the unknown software. I have in the past accepted the update, however, I need Apple to explain exactly what the update does and why it is needed. Thanks

Comment: We are not Apple, but we can try to explain it anyway :-) Can you add a screenshot of the message and the link to the Apple page you finally end up on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the need to update MacOS for iOS 14.5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419560/why-the-need-to-update-macos-for-ios-14-5) Also see [Why the need to update MacOS for iOS 14.5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419560/why-the-need-to-update-macos-for-ios-14-5)